# Обособление приложения

Tags: пунктуация, приложение

> Старик нащупал возле себя палку "герлыгу", длинную палку с крючком на конце, и поднялся.

Почему приложение "длинную палку с крючком на конце" выделяют запятыми, а не тире? Приложение ведь стоит в середине предложения, носит пояснительный характер..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Старик нащупал возле себя свою «герлыгу», длинную палку с крючком на верхнем конце, и поднялся.**

1) Скорее всего, здесь сохранена **авторская пунктуация** (обособление распространенного приложения запятыми), но по современным правилам в таких конструкциях ставится тире.

Приложение имеет явно **пояснительный характер, а также  вставочную интонацию**, то есть выделяется паузами и произносится с понижением тона.

2) В то же время обособление запятыми **соответствует основному правилу** Розенталя (но без обозначения пояснительного характера приложения):

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

1. Обособляется распространенное приложение, выраженное нарицательным существительным с зависимыми словами и относящееся к нарицательному существительному (обычно такое приложение стоит после определяемого слова, реже —-впереди него):

   Добродушный старичок, **больничный сторож**, тотчас же впустил его (Л. Т.);

3) А это **правило обособления с помощью тире:**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

10. При обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется тире:

    для выделения (с двух сторон) приложения, носящего **характер пояснения:** Достали глубиномер — **гирьку на длинной бечёвке** — и промерили глубину;